# Symfony 3 - Modify form value after submit and validation

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

In my application, I have the requirement to modify a submitted **and validated** form value.

The use case is a form with an address that is validated **and possibly corrected** by an external web service. I need to update the address in the form after the correction and inform the user about that in their newly rendered form. The user should not get a validation error after correction.

Symfony's form component does not allow modifying an already submitted form value and throws an `AlreadySubmittedException` exception.

One solution is to pass the corrected address to the template and add logic to it. But this is the wrong way, in my opinion.

Is there another solution?

Comment: Hey. Did you find a solution? How did you solve your problem? I'm facing the same issue. Thanks in advance for you feedback

Comment: Please look at the comments of the next answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you're correct, passing the corrected value to the template is not the right way.

The correct way is to add an event listener to your form and validate/correct the value there.

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;

class FooType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('address');

        $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT, function (FormEvent $event) {
            $data = $event->getData();
            // do webservice validation here and
            $data = [];

            // set new data
            $event->setData($data);
        });
    }
}
```

The [docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/dynamic_form_modification.html) for more information.

Comment: Thanks Airoude. Unfortunately I cannot use the FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT listener, because a) at this time validation hasn't been executed yet. But I can only correct the address after the validation which is implemented in an class contraint and b) I get an AlreadySubmittedException

Comment: You can set a [lower priority](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#suppressing-form-validation) so that the validator gets executed.

Comment: Yes, but this only works if the validated entity is the root entity. Validation is executed in the ValidationListener that listens to FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT but only if $form->isRoot() is true. Unfortunately my address entity is a child form. If a use a FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT listener with a low priority within it, validation has not been executed yet.

Comment: Did you try to place the listener in the child form?

Comment: Yes. In my child address form $event->getForm()->isValid() is always valid because validation hasn't been executed yet. In fact my requirements are even more complicated. My for has several child forms (user) that each have the address child form and I validate it depending on a field "How many users?"

Comment: OMG, call me an idiot! I've got it. I only need to change the properties of my address object in the validate method of my custom constraint where I talk to the webservice.

Comment: @JensSieckmann great! Didn’t know you used a constraint otherwise the answer would be obvious ;)

Comment: Sorry for omitting that point. Yes, it's a class constraint on the address entity.